# Local ASP Core 3.1 MVC App with Microsoft Authentication - Single Tenant or Multi Tenant

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, asp.net-core-3.1

Some background, I am deploying a local ASP Core 3.1 MVC Application within our companies internal network. Currently working on it in a local dev environment, but will eventually run on a linux system where the URL is routed through our DNS server and given a nicer looking url than the plain IP Address. Our organization uses Azure AD and all our employees have microsoft accounts. I am trying to only allow logins via Microsoft accounts. I have followed the Quickstart guide within the Azure Portal, but am now getting the following error : "AADSTS50194 ...  not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of the /common endpoint is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant"

The guides did not mention anything about configuring endpoints as far as I could see. I currently have it set to single tenant as it seems like it will only allow accounts that follow this format, employeesname@mycompany.com. The mycompany.com is the domain we own.

This app will service multiple users concurrently, but we only want our own employees to have access, no guests or exceptions.

Questions:
Is there a reason why I should use multi-tenancy, or is single-tenancy ok? If single tenancy, how do I go about configuring the endpoint?

I am new to 3.1 and the example project from Microsoft is 2.1 (I see where they seem to be configuring endpoints here, but not sure how to update this to 3.1)

Answer (score 0):

So after moving back and forth between attempts in the Startup.cs file

```
    services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions => {
                microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
                microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
                //microsoftOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-microsoft";
      
            });
```

I settled with the above. I changed to multi tenant because the more restrictive pages will be granted manually so if someone manages to login inside our network, with their personal MS account, it wont make much of a difference

just be sure to use this in your layout file (or any razor views):

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

to see if a user has authenticated correctly